# Confusion on getting Javascript to see a lsit of lists from Python via JSON as such

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am working on a Django app.  I need to pass back a few parameters from the server, which I do with this code:

```
num_periods = 25    
num_traces = 2
opacities = [0.5, .99]
ys = [[1,2,3,4,5],[7,6,5,4,3]]

response = {'text' : request.POST['value'],
            'num_periods' : num_periods,
            'num_traces' : num_traces,
            'opacity': opacities,
            'ys': ys
           }

return JsonResponse(response)
```

On the client side, in the Ajax callback, I have code that looks like this:

```
    success : function(data) {
        console.log('num traces = ' + data.num_traces);
        console.log('opacitiees = ' + data.opacity);
        console.log('data = ' + data.ys);
```

but, `console.log(ys)` gives `data = 1,2,3,4,5,7,6,5,4,3`, which looks flattened.

However, if I do `console.log(ys[1])`, it 'looks like' an array: `7,6,5,4,3`, though with no brackets.  So, JS is aware of the nested list structure.
But any attempt to get it into a list of lists of numbers fails.  for example this code:

```
z=[]
z.push(ys[0])
z.push(ys[1])
```

gives me back `z = 1,2,3,4,5,7,6,5,4,3` when I do `console.log("z = " + z)`

Something deeply confusing is happening here.  I also tried `Object.values(ys[0])`, but still this does not give a list.  Other ideas I have seen are a clever use of slice like so :

```
 var ys=[];
 while(list.length) ys.push(list.splice(0,5));
 console.log("ys[0]="+ys[0]);
```

which gives
     ys[0]=1,2,3,4,5,7,6,5,4,3

How do you take the JSON that was received from Python and get it to look like the basic list of lists that I clearly need?  Stuffing '[' and ']' around things before assigning does no good...

What seems very confusing is that if I do a 'loopback' within Javascript by doing something like

```
var foo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( { 'ys' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
```

then things look better: the type of foo.ys is now `Array[ Array[5], Array[5] ]`.   But the type of what I am getting with the actual Python-JS transfer is just that list of numbers, with type 'Object'.

Comment: You have got to be kidding...so much for incremental coding and validation through print() or console.log() to make really, really sure things are as you expect them to be...

Answer (score 1):

(1) use the development tools of your browser to see what is sent back and forth between the server and the browser (F12 on all browsers).

(2) you can use commas in `console.log('ys=', ys);`

I'd be very surprised if it isn't in fact a list of lists with the same values you sent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here it (implicitly) calls `toString`, which you can see doesn't put any square brackets around the array. That means it doesn't put brackets around smaller arrays either - so it *looks* like it's flat. To make it look like the object in your code, you can convert it to JSON:

```
JSON.stringify([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

will be

```
"[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
```

which you can then log or do more with. (while `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].toString()` is `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`). All of your actual data structures are entirely as you expected, the problem is just in the step of turning them into strings for output - so you don't need to do any more processing on the variables themselves, until you need to represent them as strings.